# Opening Access database drops me in code window for no reason

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, breakpoints

I created a function and an Autoexec macro that calls the function.

For some reason, when I open the database the code window opens and execution stops at the first line of code in that function. There is no run time error. There is no breakpoint set, but it is stopping where I did have a breakpoint during debugging. Breakpoints should not be remembered after closing the database. It is just sitting there waiting for me to Continue execution.

Weird.

- Brad

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by renaming the old function and copying the code to a new function that never had a breakpoint.

Anyone know the cause and a better solution?

- Brad

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints are remembered after closing the DB and this is exactly what is happening. They do not persist after the first time passed though. This is useful in your exact situation: you are trying to debug an AutoExec macro but it executes immediately. You want a breakpoint to persist, at least once, to help debugging.

You should be able to continue past it, finish execution, save (with no break point set when you hit save) close, and reopen. It should no longer break there.

Comment: There was no red dot indicating the breakpoint was still enabled. I continued execution and closed the code window, closed the database and went back in. I tried many variations of this. I did not try a Clear All Breakpoints however. If this was a sticky, phantom breakpoint, that would have a fair chance of fixing it.

Comment: You're right that there will be no red dot. the breakpoint is present nonetheless

Comment: "cleal all breakpoints" doesn't help; M$ should be sued for Access bugs #^$#^%